# "an attempt to compromise security" Only happens for 1 user on this laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop

Error when a particular user is logging into domain, Windows7 laptop. (HP 8460p)  Can't map any drives or run the logon script.  Other users can log into this laptop, and everything is just fine.   He has a WindowsXP laptop, same domain, everything works fine.

What we've tried:
- Deleted the user profile
- Re-imaged the laptop twice, changing the computer name each time (the same image was used for other laptops which are fine)
- We are able to ping the server fine that hosts the home drive

We're going to have him log onto another Windows7 laptop to see what happens, not sure what else to try.  I wondered if it might be the NTLM settings on the windows7 laptop.

-- group policies arent getting applied either.  I'm going to check the clock tomorrow.  That seems to make the most sense at this point.  Thanks :)

Comment: We'll need more information.  Have you checked the Event Logs on the laptop for errors that may be related? For example, are group policies applying OK?

Comment: Also, are the DNS settings on the laptop set to use the domain's DNS server as the first/only entry?

Answer (score 0):

IF the computer is using XP still?
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944043

Make sure Time is set correct on the machines

Check for any DNS changes

and lower on the list
Check for the many thing in group policy stuff that might be set to expire over time.
like Kerberos

Before re-imaging it again, clear the MBR first.

Comment: He said it was Windows 7, and tagged it as such.  Also, he's said that other users can log into that notebook and it works. :)

Comment: ahh, I see, the winXp one is working.